# Why does pandas python use disk space

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, temporary-files

I have a PC with two disks:

- 110GB SSD
- 1TB HDD

There is around 18GB free in the SSD.

When I run the python code below, it "uses" all the space from my SSD (I end up having only 1GB free). This code iterates on all SAS files in a folder, performs a group by operation and appends results of each file to one big dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import datetime
import numpy as np

#The function GetDailyPricePoints does the following:
#1. Imports file
#2. Creates "price" variable
#3. Performs a group by
#4. Decode byte variables and convert salesdate to date type (if needed)

def GetDailyPricePoints(inpath,infile):
    intable = pd.read_sas(filepath_or_buffer=os.path.join(inpath,infile))

    #Create price column
    intable.loc[intable['quantity']!=0,'price'] = intable['salesvalue']/intable['quantity']
    intable['price'] = round(intable['price'].fillna(0.0),0)

    #Create outtable
    outtable = intable.groupby(["salesdate", "storecode", "price", "barcode"]).agg({'key_row':'count', 'salesvalue':'sum', 'quantity':'sum'}).reset_index().rename(columns = {'key_row':'Baskets', 'salesvalue':'Sales', 'quantity':'Quantity'})

    #Fix byte values and salesdate column
    for column in outtable:
        if not column in list(outtable.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns.values): #loop non-numeric columns
            outtable[column] = outtable[column].where(outtable[column].apply(type) != bytes, outtable[column].str.decode('utf-8'))
        elif column=='salesdate': #numeric column and name is salesdate
            outtable[column] = pd.to_timedelta(outtable[column], unit='D') + pd.Timestamp('1960-1-1')

    return outtable


inpath =  r'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Transactions'
outpath = os.getcwd() + '\Export'
outfile =  'DailyPricePoints'

dirs = os.listdir(inpath)
outtable = pd.DataFrame()

#loop through SAS files in folder
for file in dirs:
    if file[-9:] == '.sas7bdat':
        outtable.append(GetDailyPricePoints(inpath,file,decimals))
```

I would like to understand what exactly is using disk space. Also, I would like to change the path where this "temporary works" are saved, to a path in my HDD.

Comment: It could be paging?

Answer (score 2):

You are copying all the data you have into RAM; you don't have enough in this case, so Python uses a page file or virtual memory instead. The only way to fix this would be to get more memory, or you could just not store everything in one big dataframe, e.g. write each file into a pickle with `outtable.to_pickle('csvfile.csv')`.

However, if you insist on storing everything in one large csv, you can append to a csv by passing a file object as the first argument:

```
out = open('out.csv', 'a')
outtable.to_csv(out, index = False)
```

doing the `.to_csv()` step within your loop.

Also, the `.append()` method for dataframes does not modify the dataframe in place, but instead returns a new dataframe (unlike the method with lists). So your last block of code probably isn't doing what you're expecting.

Comment: As you correctly assumed I store everything in one large CSV so I used the open('out.csv', 'a') .. method.

Comment: I was thinking.. Is there a way at least to change the hard disk where the page file is saved (and use my other drive)?

Comment: Yes. This is going off on a tangent, and the steps depend on the operating system, but can be found with a Google search. A quick note to make is that people usually have the page file on a/the physical drive that does *not* contain the OS, but in this case your OS drive is the SSD (while the other is not), so you'll need to do some research to weigh the pros and cons.

Comment: I wanted to let you know that in the end what really help me was to import the sas_file within a function and create outtable there. In the code I gave above it is already the case but my actual code is a bit different...
Basically, I don't create pandas dataframe variables in the global scope (hope I am using correct terminology)